# jfxmobile app fails to install on iphone emulator because of missing application files

Tags: ios, gluon

The codebase runs on desktop and Android, now the step toward iOS is needed. The fact that there is an "ERROR", but no explanation what, is strange. The main issue is that the Application folder is empty.

I see the emulator come up, the app icon appear, the install starting and then the exception is shown. Compile with --info does not reveal any additional information.

```
...
[02:05:55:833] com.gluonhq.higgs.Compiler: halfway done round 14 
[02:05:56:201] com.gluonhq.higgs.Compiler: done round 14 
[02:05:56:201] com.gluonhq.higgs.Compiler: Waiting for remaing classes to be compiled on executor  
[02:05:56:202] com.gluonhq.higgs.Compiler: active count = 0 and coresize = 2 and queuesize = 0 
[02:05:56:202] com.gluonhq.higgs.Compiler: shutdown executor 
[02:05:56:202] com.gluonhq.higgs.Compiler: shutdown executor done  
[02:05:56:202] com.gluonhq.higgs.Compiler: await term done 
[02:05:56:202] com.gluonhq.higgs.Compiler: All classes are now compiled 
[02:05:56:202] com.gluonhq.higgs.Compiler: Compiled 0 classes in 25.835 seconds 
[02:05:56:224] com.gluonhq.higgs.Higgs: non-fatal issue for class com.gluonhq.impl.charm.a.b.b.f (no known superclass) 
[02:05:56:225] com.gluonhq.higgs.Higgs: non-fatal issue for class com.gluonhq.impl.charm.a.b.b.m (no known superclass) 
[02:05:56:226] com.gluonhq.higgs.Higgs: non-fatal issue for class com.gluonhq.impl.charm.a.b.b.o (no known superclass) 
[02:05:56:226] com.gluonhq.higgs.Higgs: non-fatal issue for class com.gluonhq.impl.charm.a.b.b.v (no known superclass) 
[02:05:56:232] com.gluonhq.higgs.Higgs: ERROR for class com.sun.javafx.property.adapter.PropertyDescriptor$Listener 
[02:05:56:233] com.gluonhq.higgs.Higgs: ERROR for class com.sun.javafx.property.adapter.ReadOnlyPropertyDescriptor$ReadOnlyListener 
[02:05:56:263] com.gluonhq.higgs.Higgs: non-fatal issue for class javafx.scene.web.JSObjectIosImpl (no known superclass) 
[02:05:56:267] com.gluonhq.higgs.Higgs: non-fatal issue for class net.miginfocom.layout.BoundSize$1 (no known superclass) 
[02:05:56:268] com.gluonhq.higgs.Higgs: ERROR for class net.miginfocom.layout.LayoutUtil$1 
[02:05:56:269] com.gluonhq.higgs.Higgs: non-fatal issue for class net.miginfocom.layout.UnitValue$1 (no known superclass) 
ERR: Launch simulator on simudid: B3D4F644-FC5F-4DBE-8586-9C3D0D6E4E70 and launchDir = /Users/user/Documents/tesla/teslaApp/build/gvm/teslaApp.app

[SUB] Failed to install application. Error Domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain Code=1 "This app could not be installed at this time." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to chmod /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B3D4F644-FC5F-4DBE-8586-9C3D0D6E4E70/data/Bundle/Application/4C023753-2AC3-42BC-95E9-C46FCF4996D6/teslaApp.app/TeslaTasks : No such file or directory, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fdf2cf19870 {Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=4 "Failed to chmod /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B3D4F644-FC5F-4DBE-8586-9C3D0D6E4E70/data/Bundle/Application/4C023753-2AC3-42BC-95E9-C46FCF4996D6/teslaApp.app/TeslaTasks : No such file or directory" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to chmod /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B3D4F644-FC5F-4DBE-8586-9C3D0D6E4E70/data/Bundle/Application/4C023753-2AC3-42BC-95E9-C46FCF4996D6/teslaApp.app/TeslaTasks : No such file or directory, LegacyErrorString=ExecutableTwiddleFailed, FunctionName=-[MIExecutableBundle makeExecutableWithError:], SourceFileLine=1221, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fdf2cf1b180 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Failed to chmod /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B3D4F644-FC5F-4DBE-8586-9C3D0D6E4E70/data/Bundle/Application/4C023753-2AC3-42BC-95E9-C46FCF4996D6/teslaApp.app/TeslaTasks : No such file or directory, NSLocalizedDescription=This app could not be installed at this time.}
```

Comment: Are you running Java 9? In your MobileApplication class wrap with a `try {} catch (Throwable e) { e.printStacktrace(); }` your calls and try again. Have you tried [this](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/singleview-gluonvm) sample?

Comment: Yes, the jfxmobile plugin tells you that it requires J9. Since the install is failing, the mobile app is never started, so the try-catch is not revealing anything. Had to change the gradle options in the example to assign more memory, but it runs. I'll start moving code over to see what makes it fail, starting with the dependencies. I'll get back to it here.

Comment: Ok, I'd try the sample in the first place, so you have everything working properly, and then I'd try the project. Some dependencies could make it fail. See [this](https://github.com/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin#ios) and [this](http://docs.gluonhq.com/gluonvm/).

Comment: Initial findings show that charm:5.0.0-jdk9 is needed and not 5.0.2 (which has no jdk9 version). Really wondering how that will work out with Android & Desktop using the jdk8 version.

Comment: See this [build](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/blob/master/singleview-gluonvm/singleview-gluonvmApp/build.gradle#L29) file. That is why I recommended starting with the sample. See also its readme.

Comment: Already working from the example build file. But Java 9 is not an option on Android, it requires 8 (or at least that was what was twittered by Johan). I initially wanted to do an all 9 project. So the readme is not correct.